# Moving a Drupal 6.x site to MediaTemple and getting the WSOD

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, mediatemple, wsod

I'm trying to move a Drupal site over to a MediaTemple (DV) account and keep getting the WSOD.  If I move the site over, using the same procedures, to a MediaTemple (GS) account everything works just fine.

I've tried pouring through the WSOD docs to pinpoint the problem, but clearly, IMO, this has to be something unique to the settings on a DV account vs a GS account and the problem doesn't lie with Drupal itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to narrow down the problem some more. If you've done everything in the [White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043) handbook page, can you provide more detail about what you found? Specifically, try enabling error reporting by adding the following at the top of your index.php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

That should get any errors being generated to display on the page and should help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Hi Matt V, doing so results in a silent WSOD.  I've not gone through all the other fixes because a exact replica of the setup works on a GS account so I don't believe a module or errant ?> can be causing the issue.  I'm almost positive it's some nuance between DV and GS account I just dont know what.